# Rake task for multiple databases in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When running generators and migration we can mention name of database in case of multiple databases like this → bin/rails generate migration CreateDogs name:string --database animals

is there anything similar for running one time rake tasks? where we can mention name of db to connect with like this.

bin/rake one_time_tasks:testing --database animals

Is there any plans in near future by rails to support this?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection

You should check this out, I didn't try it myself but this looks like what you want

Comment: we can do that way. but I need something similar to  this command. `bin/rails generate migration CreateDogs name:string --database animals`